# CreateProcess with specific parent

Tags: c++, winapi

For standard exe programs I am aware I can use `CreateProcess` and thread attribute `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS` to specify the parent of the new process.

However when I try to launch something like `diskmgmnt.msc` I need to use the `ShellExecute` api instead. In this case how do I specify the parent of the new process.

Comment: only way - direct call `CreateProcess[AsUser]`. in your case you can run `"mmc.exe" "C:\Windows\system32\diskmgmt.msc"` and you must be in general elevated process

Comment: diskmgmnt.msc is not an executable file.  it is a plugin for mmc.exe.  ShellExecute/Ex knows this, CreateProcess doesn't.  Consider running [mmc.exe yourself](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749428%28v=ws.11%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) as a workaround.

Comment: I'm needing the shell functionality to launch the required exe automatically regardless of extension.

Comment: shell not give this. especially if you use *runas* verb - in this case `CreateProcess` called from another process. if you not use this verb, possible set hook on `CreateProcessInternalW` in own process, for provide this attribute. but "normally" this (`PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_PARENT_PROCESS`) not supported by shell without some hooks

Comment: seems like `AssocQueryString` might be the way forward so that I can then call `CreateProcess`

Comment: The parent of a process is recorded by Windows, but not used for anything useful. Why do you think you need to set a process' parent? This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: @IInspectable - this not exactly. say token for new process will be get from parent process, but not from process which call `CreateProcess`. handles also will be inherit from parent.